# Mocking psycopg2 Exceptions in Django Unit Tests

Tags: python, django, psycopg2, python-unittest

I'm struggling to write unit tests in `Django` for specific `psycopg2` errors that ultimately raise `django.db.IntegrityError` as the end result.

Typically I'd use `mock.patch` and have the `side_effect` set to the exception I would like raised.

Ex.

```
with mock.patch(
    "path_to.method_that_throws_integrity_error",
        side_effect=IntegrityError(),
    ) as mock_method:
        self.assertEqual(value, value_two)
```

This works great if I cared about the next steps after every `IntegrityError`.

However, in the case of this test. I only care about the logic in my code that follows `psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation` which eventually bubbles up and throws an `IntegrityError` which I check the `error.__cause__.diag.constraint_name` and handle logic based on the result.

If the `UniqueViolation` is thrown, I have custom logic that currently performs an action. If an `IntegrityError` is thrown that is not a `UniqueViolation` I want the error to raise so I'm alerted that there is an issue.

I've tried many things, and cannot mock raise the `UniqueViolation` so that it sets the same `psycopg2.extensions.Diagnostics` object as the one that I get from actually throwing the error by violating the unique constraint in my Db. I also cannot set the `__cause__` on the `IntegrityError` as the `UniqueViolation`.

What I would like is something like this -

```
def side_effect():
    try:
        raise UniqueViolation({"constraint_name": "my_unique_constraint"}) # not sure how to set the constraint name
    except UniqueViolation as e
        raise IntegrityError from e

with mock.patch(
    "path_to.method_that_throws_integrity_error",
        side_effect=side_effect(),
    ) as mock_method:
        self.assertEqual(value, value_two)
```

With the above, I'd be able to call my database function, raise the unique exception, and test in a Unit Test that the appropriate logic is called. I know the logic works because of being able to grab the exception in a true violation of the unique constraint, but I want coverage.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about right way to do that but you can just use monkey patching to set constraint_name attribute to exception and use function name without calling itself.
I mean something like that:

```
def side_effect():
    try:
        exception = UniqueViolation()
        exception.constraint_name = "my_unique_constraint"
        raise exception
    except UniqueViolation as e:
        raise IntegrityError from e

with mock.patch(
"path_to.method_that_throws_integrity_error",
    side_effect=side_effect,
) as mock_method:
    self.assertEqual(value, value_two)
```

This should workю

**Upd**
Or better you can just create dummy exceptions class for the test. This can help avoid monkey patching:

```
def side_effect():
    class DummyException(Exception):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(PGError, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.constraint_name = "my_unique_constraint"

    try:
        raise DummyException
    except UniqueViolation as e:
        raise IntegrityError from e
```

And maybe you should use psycopg2.errorcodes if you don't: there are many postgresql-specific codes that help to avoid magic numbers and strings